# CXF is ignoring Spring bean configuration

Tags: java, web-services, spring, cxf, jax-rs

I have a web application which is exposing a rest web service by cxf jax-rs. In my application context file I have something like this:

```
    ...
<bean id="service" class="SomeClass">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <ref bean="bean1" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1"
        value="some value" />

</bean>

<jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="service" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
    ...
```

I also have a constructor in my service class that accepts those two parameters and initializes the service.

When I deploy my application, spring context loader is creating the service bean correctly and the correct constructor is getting called. The problem is when the first Rest request comes to service. Cxf Jax-rs is creating its own instance by "default constructor" and I will lose those two properties.

The same thing happens if I user property setters instead of constructor args. When I researched cxf jax-rs, none of the examples had a service which has some properties! Is there a reason for this or is this some implementation constraint by cxf?

Any ideas?

Comment: I use service beans with arguments to constructors, and they work just fine. What app context file are you using? Web.xml or cxf.xml?

Comment: I am using web.xml. I have all spring/cxf configurations inside application-context.xml file and I am referencing it in my web.xml.  <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/application-context.xml
     WEB-INF/classes/security.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>.

Comment: @VirtuallyReal are you using the web.xml too?

Comment: I dont get it, even i have some dependecy injections done by appcontext.xml in my service class, it just works fine. Are you sure that by default a new instance of your service clas is being created on request...??

Comment: I do this all the time, I would be curious about seeing your actual service code and what you are trying to do. The Spring Lifecycle will inject the dependencies during bean processing after the BeanFactoryPostProcessors have run. Unless you are using the new keyword somewhere, you should never get a different instance of your service bean. Can you please more specific code and include your service class, your full config, and your web.xml.